# Does a motor with twice the load go twice as slow?

Tags: motor, dc-motor, speed

This may be a dumb question, but I was wondering if a DC motor with twice the load goes twice as slow? If an explanation could be provided as to why or why not, that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Edit: I don't know if it is important, but this question is referring to a small load that the motor can spin relatively easily (for example, 2 kg vs 1 kg)

Comment: If friction is negligible **no** power is needed to "spin" a given mass (1 or 2 kg); only to accelerate. If friction is not negligible it depends on the particular type of friction (is it proportional to speed, or proportional to square of speed,...?). What I want to say is: unless you just want to lift the mass mass is not a good measuremnt for load. Ideally you should talk about torque per revolutions per time which is (mechanical) power. If you equate that to electrical power you have already answerd your question.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Where would the friction be coming from?

Comment: I don't now your setup so you should know better than I. I just can guess: bearings, gear, air resistance (if it is a fan),...

Comment: For a "standard DC motor setup," with just an axle connecting the motor and rotor, could the friction change when the mass of the wheel is doubled?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not a dumb question and no, the speed does not double or halve.

A rule of thumb for most types of motors is:

- voltage is related to speed;
- current is related to torque.

Voltage x current or speed x torque is power.

So with the same voltage and double the current, the speed will be almost the same and the torque will be about double.

c-:

Comment: Thank you for the response!  So does a motor just stall when it does not have enough torque (from the current) to reach a speed (from the voltage)?

Comment: You can also think of it like this, speed = voltage = 0 (a short) and the current will be maximum, only limited by power supply and winding resistance, (way higher than the design current or torque)  and this happens to all motors under starting conditions.

Comment: Speed-torque curves can be used to see exactly what happens - [link](http://lancet.mit.edu/motors/motors3.html) (remember that these are also approximated voltage - current curves)

Answer (score -1):

A motor converts electrical energy to rotational movement (torque), every motor has a maximum torque that it can generate based on it's construction.

Now when the load is attached it produce reverse energy that counter the supplied electrical energy (think it of as for every action there is an equal and opposite action), as you increase the load the reverse energy also increases once the load is above the rated condition the reverse energy will be more than the supplied energy and will hinder the forward motion i.e torque, as you increase the load the motor stops running   at which both the energy are equal